# Is there a grading standard for security that I can apply to my MVC3 web site?

Tags: appsec, web-application

I'm looking for a standardised set of tests or scoring measures I can apply to my web site to be able to quantify it's standard or level of security. I can do some research and compile a check-list myself, but I am hoping there is something standardised, something independent of me that my client and the users of our site will appreciate more than just something I compiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you might be looking for something like the [OWASP ASVS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Application_Security_Verification_Standard_Project).  It defines four levels of rigor, each of which has an associated set of verification activities.  Once a client has decided the level at which their application should reside, you will have a concrete list of security activities that should be performed to get to that level.

Comment: Very interesting looking project. Lots of reading for me.